# Database model for different range of prices for products

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am trying to design a database for prices of metal rods. The metal rods are priced based on the following logic.

- If the bar is made of iron it is priced per kg.
- If the bar is made of steel it is priced per kg.
- If the bar is made of aluminum it's price is based on the length.
- Potentially new ways to price a rod.

The problem I am having is how to link the material to a price with the consideration of the two types of pricing rules, by weight or by a range.

For example this is how I would "draw" the table, all the prices are completely made up.

```
+-----------+------------------+
| Material  | Price            |
+-----------+------------------+
| Iron      | $0.5             |
+-----------+------------------+
| Steel     | $0.8             |
+-----------+------------------+
| Aluminium |+--------+-------+|
|           || Length | Price ||
|           |+--------+-------+|
|           || 100mm  | $10   ||
|           || 200mm  | $18   ||
|           || 500mm  | $35   ||
|           || 1000mm | $50   ||
|           |+--------+-------+|
+-----------+------------------+
```

---

I am using MySQL.

I am very new to SQL so I do not know where to even begin with this. I'm stuck because I don't now how to break down the one-to-one and one-to-many in the same column. with the additional requirement.

Comment: Material , unit_price , unit , qty ?

Comment: @RonakBhatt: The design the OP came up with is in the question.

Comment: @RonakBhatt instead this is a legit and interesting question IMHO

Comment: @juergend- That was my fault .. i corrected that... actually i thought about design of database means query.. thats why i asked that...

Comment: @RonakBhatt I added more details to the bottom

Comment: Your DB design is not normalized; this will get you into trouble sooner or later. Beau's and Giammin's answers are. Read up on normalization e.g. http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this model should go for every new type or price changes. You can also extend it to manage old prices history

```
idMaterial    material  idPriceType
-----------------------------------
1              iron        1
2              steel       1
3              alu         2


idPriceType   name     unit
---------------------------------
1             weight   kg
2             length   mm

idMaterial  price    unitForPrice
---------------------------------
1           0.5      1
2           0.8      1
3           10       100
3           18       200
3           35       500
3           50       1000
```

Answer (score 1):

For an extendable design you could have:

metal, unit_type_id, units, price 
Iron, 1, 1, 0.5
Steel, 1, 1, 0.8
Aluminium, 2, 100, 10
Aluminium, 2, 200, 18

---

with another table unit_type

id, type
1, weight (kg)
2, length (mm)